# ADB push sync but delete files at destination that don't exist at the origin

Tags: adb, sync, rsync

I'm sure I did this a few months back, but I'm drawing a complete blank.

I'm syncing my music using from my computer to my phone via usb using:

`adb push --sync local remote`

That's all fine until I rename a folder locally and then it adds it remotely, but doesn't delete the remote copy: duplicates things

I'm sure last time I just added `--delete` to the end like you can do on `rsync`, but it seems that's not valid, so I must have done something different.

Can anyone enlighten me!? All the googling and reading of docs hasn't helped!

Comment: Have you tried adb-sync or it's successor [better-adb-sync](https://github.com/jb2170/better-adb-sync)?